# Get AzureAD users from current machine with C#

Tags: c#, azure, active-directory

I'm working on a desktop application that runs on multiple machines, some of them included into an Azure Active Directory.

The final goal is to read all machine users.
I was able to read local users and users from regular Active Directories but I also need to read users from Azure AD (as they can log in to Windows like other users) but not with Graph API because I can't depend on a single Azure AD - it must work for any current Azure AD.

Any guidance? Thank you.

Comment: Maybe this [sample](https://azure.microsoft.com/en-us/resources/samples/active-directory-dotnet-native-desktop/) could help?

Comment: The issue with this is that I can't configure the app to work with one single Auzre AD. The app is supposed to get users from any AD it runs on (must work for multiple customers Azure AD setups).